# Can confuration for a progam running in a container/pod be placed in a Deployment yaml instead of ConfigMap yaml?

Tags: kubernetes

Can a confuration for a progam running in container/pod be placed in a Deployment yaml instead of ConfigMap yaml - like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
          -name: "MyConfigKey"
           value: "MyConfigValue"
```

Comment: it is not a good practice. You can use either configMaps or volume concept for storing configuration files

Comment: using the volume, you can keep your configuration files in a physical location and that will get mount to the preferred location inside the pod, use that. You can change the configuration anytime while running the pod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Single environment

Putting values in environment variables in the `Deployment` works.

**Problem:** You should not work on the environment that is the production environment, so you will need at least another environment.

Using docker, containers and Kubernetes makes it very easy to create more than one environment.

### Multiple environements

When you want to use more than one environment, you want to keep the difference as small as possible. This is important to fast detect problems and to limit the management needed.

**Problem:** Maintaining the difference between environments and also avoid unique problems (config drift / [snowflake servers](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/SnowflakeServer.html)).

Therefore, keep as much as possible common for the environments, e.g. use the same `Deployment`.

Only use unique instances of `ConfigMap`, `Secret` and probably `Ingress` for each app and environment.

Comment: So, for production environment - if I shouldn't be working on it then keeping configuration in ConfigMap is not a good idea too? That means that for production the only option is to keep configuration in a file on a PersistentVolume, isn't it?

Comment: you usually use the same `Deployment` for all environments, then you have separate `ConfigMap` for each environment, e.g. one configMap for **test**, one for **staging** one for **pre-prod** and one for **prod** - but it all depends on how many environments you have, maybe just **dev** and **prod**.

Comment: Using `kustomize` with `base` for Deployment and `overlays` for each environment is a good setup for this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#bases-and-overlays

Answer (score 3):

This is my approach when you want to set env directly from deployment:

If you using Helm:

1. Helm `values.yaml` file:

```
deployment:
  env:
    enabled: false
    vars:
      KEY1: VALUE1
      KEY2: VALUE2
```

2. Deployment templates `deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ...

          {{- if .Values.deployment.env.enabled }}
          env:
            {{- range $key, $val := .Values.deployment.env.vars }}
            - name: {{ $key }}
              value: {{ $val | quote }}
            {{- end}}
          {{- end }}

        ...
```

And if you just want to apply directly from `kubectl` command and `deployment.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ...

          env:
            - name: key1
              value: value1
            - name: key2
              value: value2

        ...
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using your first approach (Helm values.yaml and template) over writing the configuration values directly in deployment.yaml?

Comment: Helm is a package management system for Kubernetes. Using a packaging format called charts, someone can package an application--like Kafka or Apache HTTP, for example--in a format that anyone else can deploy on a Kubernetes cluster with just a few commands, while making few or no manual changes to YAML files. Many advantage I can list but Helm help you management k8s resources centralize, easy to deploy and rollback, explicit declaration. In above example,  you can see that I can use loop over the env and Helm will generate the template for  you. Reference here: [Helm](https://helm.sh/)